# How to create polygons from 3D points in CSV?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, 3d, vector-layer

I'm trying to create polygons associate to given .csv files. On the polygon I would have to be able to read the coordinates x, y (AND Z) because I need to interpolate points and work with them. I know this can be done OpenJUMP, because I've been doing it for a while, but I've not been able to find how to do it in QGIS. Does anyone know how to do it?

ps. I've tried archeoCAD, but it doesn't fit my needs because it creates polygons as a single unit, without the information of the points on the chart, and I'm trying with CADtools, but I'm not really being able to figure it out.

---

My csv contains vertices, and the rows contain (comma separated, without header, nor any space) 1 = coordinate x, 2 = y, 3 = z, 4 = string, 5 = string (row 4 is a common field). I do know how to create .csv files, and how to create a polygon out of the resulting points. The problem is that I'd need that polygon to include the x,y and z coordinates on the same layer... I've tried several options, but I'm starting to think maybe this is not possible in QGIS?

Comment: To clarify, does your csv contain the vertices of your polygons?

Comment: What is the format of your CSV file? Does each row describe a polygon, somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Extending Allison's answer, which will insert a CSV into QGIS, you can then use "Vector  >  Geoprocessing Tools  >  Convex hull".

The convex hull tool will create a minimum boundary polygon around a group of points. You have the option to create this polygon around all points, or create several polygons around point clusters that share common attributes ( you mentioned in your comment that field 4 is a common field).

Answer (score -1):

In QGIS, you'd use Layer > Add delimited text layer

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, this option creates the points layer on QGIS, but what I'd need is to draw a polygon out of those points, which would include the information of x, y and z on the same layer...